# TextBlock won't display the rest of it's text even when it's resized

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro

An app I'm working on retrieves information from the Internet and displays it in-app in a series of Grids inside of a StackPanel, itself nested inside of a ScrollViewer.

My problem is this: The app shows a short summary of the content, and the idea is that clicking the content makes the Grid and TextBlock expand to show the rest of the content, however resizing the TextBlock doesn't show the text that was cut off by being too short originally. The TextBlock is created dynamically in c# code.

Additionally, but not vital: I don't know how to get the full required height from the TextBlock to change it's text to, and without it I have to set the new size to a static number, which I feel detracts from the UX of my app.

Thanks,
Jase

---

**Update:** This is the code used to generate the TextBlock:

```
this.message = new TextBlock()
{
    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
    TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap,
    MaxWidth = getWidth()
};
if(post.message != null) { message.Text = post.message; }
```

**Update 2:** This is the code that creates the StackPanel (XAML):

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource MainColumn}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" SizeChanged="Feed_SizeChanged">
    <StackPanel x:Name="Feed"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

This is where the parent Grid is generated:

```
Post grid = new Post() { Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 5) };
Feed.Children.Add(grid);
grid.layoutPost(oldCount, count--, post, Feed, this);
```

The height of the Grid is set in the layoutPost method, and ends up at 75px, Post is a class that extends Grid, and is defined here:

```
class Post : Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you leave the Height of the TextBlock undefined and set TextWrapping="Wrap" - the TextBlock should automatically grow to the size required to fit its Text.

Another problem you might encounter is if you are trying to put large quantities of these TextBlocks in your ScrollViewer. That might not perform too well since you are not virtualizing your content and loading that much text requires a lot of CPU power for the layout. Usually using a ListBox or a ListView is a better choice for such scenarios since they use a VirtualizingStackPanel to lay out their child elements.

Comment: I haven't defined the height on my TextBlock at all, and wrapping is set to Wrap. I'll update the question with the code I used to generate the TextBlock. Also, I used a ListView at first, but changed it as I wasn't happy with how it allowed users to select list items.

Comment: You can disable selection in LV. You would also need to share the code for the panel where your TextBlocks are hosted.

Comment: The container for the TextBlocks is simply a Grid with height set, contained in an XAML generated StackPanel in a ScrollViewer, neither have anything other than the default properties.

Comment: I'll post the code anyway a bit later. Have to rush off for now.

Comment: Well, if the parent Grid's height is set, then obviously you might not be able to fit all the content of the TextBlocks within it since their height will be limited by the height of the grid.

Comment: I understand that, but when the Grid is clicked, it expands its height so that it can fit the full text size. I'll update the question with the other code now too.

Comment: I suggest that instead of expanding that grid - you open a new popup or page with same content on full screen or somewhere else in the app. Perhaps something like in the Rowi app.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into that. I'll mark this answer as accepted as it has been helpful and I've learned a bit about the controls I'm working with, and ultimately produced a solution that will work better. I'll have a look at the Rowi app to see what you're suggesting in action.